# VS code source control filled with junk files

Tags: git, flutter, visual-studio-code, version-control

Title. Im developing a flutter project, and my source control is filled with hundreds of random android/ios/build files every time I modify a single file. How do I get rid of this? I have a github repository and I cloned it and this started happening. I only want the files that I directly modified to be showing up in the source control.

(Note the .gitignore was me trying to fix the issue I have since cleared out that file)

[image: Image linked here]

Comment: all these files are in the `build` directory, and as the name suggests this should not be put in the repository so add this dir to the `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try with default .gitignore file for flutter project

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json
    enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why this is being downvoted so hard, I don't remember deleting my gitignore and this may help others